# subdomain of subdomain not resolving

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, godaddy, webmin, virtualmin

I have a `example.com` domain which points to a server, and also I have created a subdomain with `A` Record for it like `sub.example.com` to point it to another server.

Now I want to manage all subdomains of `sub.example.com` like `sub2.sub.example.com` to be managed with the second server. How should I do that?
I dont want to put another `A` record in Godaddy for `sub2.sub`, I just want to say all subdomains of `sub.example.com` should be resolved on the second server

FYI: I have Virtualmin on the second server, so there is a DNS server installed with it to resolve incoming requests.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean "resolved _to_ the second server" or do you mean "resolved _using_ records provided by the second server"?

Comment: @grawity resolved using records provided by the second server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to create a delegation, which uses **NS** records. Create an NS record pointing to a name that has A/AAAA records which point to the new DNS server:

```
myserver.domain.com.    AAAA  2001:db8::1
myserver.domain.com.    A     192.0.2.1

sub.domain.com.         NS    myserver.domain.com.
```

Delegation covers all subdomains **and** the name itself. All A/AAAA queries for `sub.domain.com.` (and any other record types) will actually be resolved using the second server.

This means that you should also remove all other records for `sub.domain.com.` from the parent zone – instead, add them to the child zone (the second server).

**Other variants**

NS records *are* allowed to point at a nameserver name that's covered by the delegation itself, but when doing so, those A/AAAA records must be duplicated between *both* the parent and child domains (they become "glue records").

For example, this is valid:

```
mysrv.sub.domain.com.   A    192.0.2.1   ; needs to exist on both zones!
sub.domain.com.         NS   mysrv.sub.domain.com.
```

This is *probably* also valid but I would not recommend doing it:

```
sub.domain.com.         A    192.0.2.1   ; needs to exist on both zones!
sub.domain.com.         NS   sub.domain.com.
```